# Force PowerShell to use a specific port

Tags: powershell, tcp

I am using a PowerShell script to change the local password on several remote laptops. I had to open up all the TCP ports on the remote laptops to get this to work though because the ports were all over the place. Is there a way to force this action over a specific port so I can specify to only open that port on the remote laptops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to find out what ports the firewall where blocking when attempting this and open those ports.

Answer (score 1):

You should run `enable-psremoting` or `winrm quickconfig` on your remote servers to set up the OS for accepting remote management commands. This will open necessary ports, without extra actions on your behalf.

Comment: I have done both of those already, but still failing until I open up all the TCP ports on the firewall.